# Return results when size range has one or more values greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, sum

I have a ledger entry table used to calculate item stock (where sales and returns are summed to calc current stock).

It seems pretty straight forward to sum this quantity column using:

```
select [Item Ledger].[Location],[Item].[Item Division Code],
[Ledger Entry].[Item],[Variant Code],
SUM([Item Ledger].[Quantity]) as 'stock'
from [Item Ledger]
join [Item] on [Ledger Entry].[Item] = [Item].[no_]
where [Item Ledger].[Location Code] = 'xx'
group by [Item Ledger].[Location],[Item Ledger].[Item],
[Variant Code],[Item].[Item Division Code]
order by [Item Ledger Entry].[Item]
```

What i'm trying to see is a list where the item may have 1 or more variants in stock but the other variants may have 0 in stock. At the moment I can either return all 0 stock/all stock or all stock that has a value. I can't see how to return items that have variants with both zero and a value (but exclude all items that only have 0 against the variants)

eg

I may have one shirt (shirt 1) with variant codes (sizes) small (s), medium(m), large (l)
running the code above, It may show I have 2 small, 1 medium and 0 large in stock

it may also show for shirt2 I have 0 small, 0 medium and 0 large

What i would like to see is only shirt1 as i am not interested in styles that have only 0 values across the whole size range.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want. Could you add some examples of existing data and data that you want to get?

Comment: In particular, are the values you are looking for with "0" stored in the table with "0" or are they missing from the table?

Comment: Hi MikkaRin. I have added a few more notes to the question.

Comment: Gordon, the values are calculate via a sum. Its the query results that i'm looking to differentiate between items that have 0 stock across all size ranges and stock where they could be a zero against 1 size, but could be in stock against another size

Comment: Does the question make sense now

Comment: Can you add some data that might be in each of the tables and what the query in your example would return? (Aside: you need to use '@' + username in order to alert people that you have responded to their comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand the question. Right now your data looks like:

> ```
> Item      Varient     Stock
> Shirt1        S           2
> Shirt1        M           1
> Shirt1        L           0
> Shirt2        S           0
> Shirt2        M           0
> Shirt2        L           0
> Shirt3        M           2
> Shirt4        L           0
> Shirt5        S           1
> Shirt5        M           2
> Shirt5        L           4
> ```

However, you only want the data for Shirt1. You aren't interested in shirt3 or shirt4 because there is only one varient, so they just don't fit. You don't want shirt2 because there isn't anything in stock, and you don't want shirt5 because there isn't anything out of stock. Here is the approach that I recommend:

```
select  il.Location,
        i.ItemDivisionCode,
        il.Item,
        VariantCode,
        SUM(il.Quantity) as 'stock'
 from ItemLedger il
 join Item i
    on il.Item = i.no_
where il.LocationCode = 'xx'
and Case When ( Select sum(1)
                 From ItemLedger il2
                Where   il2.item = il.item
                 and    il2.quantity = 0
                Group by il2.item) > 0
    Then ISNULL(
                    (Select sum(1)
                      From  ItemLedger il2
                     Where  il2.item = il.item
                      and   il2.quantity > 0
                     Group by il2.item)
                , 0)
    Else 0
    End > 0

group by    il.Location,
            il.Item,
            VariantCode,
            i.ItemDivisionCode
order by il.Item
```

Now, let's talk about what this query means. To start off with, I grabbed the query that you posted and added aliases. Aliases are essentially giving a table a nickname. Instead of referencing the table name over and over again, you can use the alias and sql will know what you are talking about.

Now, the meat of what you are looking for is in the where clause, namely the case statement. A case statement is essentially sql's version of an `if... then... else...` statement. The first part of the case statement is the condition.

```
Case When ( Select sum(1)
                     From ItemLedger il2
                    Where   il2.item = il.item
                     and    il2.quantity = 0
                    Group by il2.item) > 0
```

In this case, the condition is a subquery. This subquery is looking in the item legder table for all the items of the same type as the row we are currently looking at with 0 as the quantity in stock. So, for shirt1 this subquery will return 1. For shirt2, this subquery is going to bring back 3. Now the condition part comes in. If the value we get back is greater than 0, we're going to move on to the next part of the case statement.

```
Then ISNULL(
            (Select sum(1)
              From  ItemLedger il2
             Where  il2.item = il.item
              and   il2.quantity > 0
             Group by il2.item)
            , 0)
```

Now we are looking to see how many varients there are that are in stock. For shirt1, this subquery is going to pull back 2. For shirt2, this query will pull back null. Why? Well, the subquery is saying to count how many rows there are that have a quantity greater than 0. Shirt2 doesn't have any rows with a quantity greater than 0. If we were to run the subquery itself, we just wouldn't get any information. How can you sum no information? Luckily for us, we can handle this. The `ISNULL` says, if this query doesn't bring anything back, let's just say that it brought back 0.

What happens where the 'if' part of our case statement comes back as false? Instead of going to the 'then' part of the case statement, we are going to head here:

```
Else 0
```

This really does just say return 0 as a number. Then, we are done with the case statement because we have covered all of our bases. Now, we aren't completely done yet. The case statement is contained in the where clause. We have said

```
and --the case statement
```

Everything in the where clause must return true or false, we cannot evaluate `and 0` or `and 12`. So, we have to do something with the information we just found to make the result a boolean. We do this by requiring the result of the case statement to be greater than 0. I'm sure right now you are thinking "will this work?"

It actually will. Here's why. If the item doesn't have a varient where the stock is 0, we will get 0 from the case and rule that out (since 0 isn't greater than 0). If the item does have a varient with stock 0, we are checking if they have something with stock greater than 0. If they don't, we still return 0 and rule that out.

This may seem like a convoluted answer to a simple problem, but in reality the problem is not so simple. You are asking about information about different data points. What you are trying to do is like asking your friend Joe if Steve is going to the movies tonight. Joe doesn't know anything about Steve. The only way to get that information is by reaching out to Steve and finding out the information from him. The subqueries essentially do that by pulling data from completely different select statements.